# Linux Rehat 6.4 pyodbc connection to Netezza Database Issue

Tags: python, linux, unicode, pyodbc, netezza

## Code

```
print pyodbc.dataSources()

print "Connecting via ODBC"

get a connection, if a connect cannot be made an exception will be raised here
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={NetezzaSQL Unicode};SERVER=localhost;PORT=5668;DATABASE=Database;UID=santiago;PWD=ha123;")
```

## Output

I am getting this error and I also had Netezza driver installed and I have unixODBC-devel installed. I am also new to linux. Can I please get help?

```
{}

Connecting via ODBC

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 15, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={NetezzaSQL Unicode};SERVER=localhost;PORT=5668;DATABASE=Database;UID=santiago;PWD=ha123>;")
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnectW)')
```

Answer (score 0):

The OBDC  configuration file needs to be altered to access the correct netezza driver. You should find this file in /etc.

Answer (score -1):

What happens when you give following?
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={NetezzaSQL};SERVER=localhost;PORT=5668;DATABASE=Database;UID=santiago;PWD=ha123;")

Comment: It gave the same error. I think I have the answer. My team thinks that the ODBC Netezza driver was not installed correctly on our server. I'll keep you updated when the issue is fixed or if we have anther issue.